# rsyslog expression based filter - 'startswith' not working

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, rsyslog

I am trying to filter out some `sshd` logs like these into a separate file:

```
 sshd[14913]: Did not receive identification string from 10.16.0.2
```

I tried the following, and it worked:

```
if $programname == 'sshd' and
   $syslogfacility-text == 'security' and
   $syslogseverity == '6' then -/var/log/sshinfo.log
& stop
```

But this also matches user login/logout, so i tried to add a 
a *message-match* filter:

```
if $programname == 'sshd' and
   $msg startswith 'Did not'  and    # <---
   $syslogseverity == '6' then -/var/log/sshinfo.log
& stop
```

It doesn't work! (although `contains` works)

Is `startswith` broken, or is this usage incorrect?

Version:

```
# rsyslogd -v
rsyslogd 7.4.4, compiled with:
    FEATURE_REGEXP:             Yes
    FEATURE_LARGEFILE:          No
    GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:      Yes
    FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
    32bit Atomic operations supported:  Yes
    64bit Atomic operations supported:  Yes
    Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
    uuid support:               Yes
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a template with something like `msg is -->%msg%` to see how the message part begins, but in general it begins with a space, so just try

```
$msg startswith ' Did not'  and
```